# Force Cron to run only on one server

Tags: server, cron

Given a site running on server A and server B with a load balancer, shared database/etc, and a regular wp-cron task, how would I make sure that wp-cron only runs on server A, never on server B?

Comment: Could you define a Constant, depending on which Server your `wp-config.php` is loaded? Afterwards it should be a piece of cake, making a conditional in the callback function of the `wp-cron` task.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but lets say this cron task is important, and it fires on server B, constant doesn't match, abort! Next time round, server B, same again, client notices that the 2 cron jobs for that day haven't fired, and raises a support issue.

Comment: Yeah, got your problem. And got a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently testing this in wp-config.php:

```
if ( php_uname('n') == 'wp4' ) {
    define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
}
```

Where wp4 is the name of the second server in the setup

Answer (score 1):

I would create a constant in the `wp_config.php` defining which Server you are on. So far so good, not really magic.

The tricky part, as you mentioned is to get the cron running for sure, and not aborting if it's accidentally the wrong server. Try the function like this:

```
function my_cron_callback() {
    if ( MY_SERVER_SETUP == "SERVER_A" ) {
        do_the_cron_action();
    } else {
        set_transient( 'do_the_cron_on_server_a', 'true' );
    }
}
```

Now, you have a transient set when the cron would run on the other server, but is not executed. The Function `do_the_cron_action` contains your script.

The last step is to hook a function to the `init`, checking if the server is ServerA and if the transient is set.

```
function check_if_a_should_execute() {
    if( MY_SERVER_SETUP == "SERVER_A" && get_transient( 'do_the_cron_on_server_a' == 'true' ) {
        do_the_cron_action();
        delete_transient( 'do_the_cron_on_server_a' );
    }
} 
add_action( 'init', 'check_if_a_should_execute' );
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Nice, the cronjob has a chance of being particularly heavy, perhaps adding to a later action rather than init might be better, one will test this afternoon!

Comment: That depends on your preference and what the cronjob has to do. But I hope this method works for you :)